# Query Outlook Addins with Powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook-addin

I have to query my Outlook Add-ins and check if two specific ones are installed.

This is what I have:

```
$searchScopes = "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins","HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins"
$searchScopes | % {Get-ChildItem -Path $_ | % {Get-ItemProperty -Path $_.PSPath} | Select-Object @{n="Name";e={Split-Path $_.PSPath -leaf}},FriendlyName,Description} | Sort-Object -Unique -Property name
```

This shows me all installed Add-ins. Now I dont know how to filter the result to get a true or false.

Like the following

```
If List contains 'addin1' then 'addin1' installed = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a list of addins to check if they are installed? What do you want to do once you have found that something is installed or not?

You could make use of the `-in` operator, which checks a value against a list and is true if the value is in the list. All this code does is print to host; the logic in the loop will need to be changed to match your requirements.

```
$searchScopes = "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins","HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins"
$names = $searchScopes | % {Get-ChildItem -Path $_ | % {Get-ItemProperty -Path $_.PSPath} | Select-Object @{n="Name";e={Split-Path $_.PSPath -leaf}},FriendlyName,Description} | Sort-Object -Unique -Property name

if("addin1" -in $names){
    Write-Host "addin1 is installed."
}
```

Comment: I have to check which users have the addins installed. I then write the results to a Log file. But your solution works great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using your code, add the second line into a variable

```
$searchScopes = "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins","HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins"
$Results = $searchScopes | % {Get-ChildItem -Path $_ | % {Get-ItemProperty -Path $_.PSPath} | Select-Object @{n="Name";e={Split-Path $_.PSPath -leaf}},FriendlyName,Description} | Sort-Object -Unique -Property name
```

then query the results:

```
$Results.Name -contains 'TeamViewerMeetingAddIn.AddIn'
```

or

```
$Results.FriendlyName -match 'Google Apps'
```

To filter:

```
$Results | ? {$_.Name -contains 'TeamViewerMeetingAddIn.AddIn'}
```